# Laravel 8 collection erroring saying instance of model passed instead of resource

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a simple controller;

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Databases;

use App\Models\Database;
use App\Http\Resources\DatabaseCollection;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DatabaseController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return new DatabaseCollection(Database::all());
    }
}
```

It is meaning to return a list of database credentials which we store in the DB;

The collection resource looks like so;

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use App\Models\Database;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class DatabaseCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $this->collection->transform(function (Database $database) {
            return new DatabaseResource($database);
        });

        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

and then the standard resource looks like so;

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use App\Models\Database;

class DatabaseResource extends Resource
{
    public function toArray($request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'host' => $this->host,
            'port' => $this->port,
        ];
    }
}
```

This is returning an error;

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Resources\DatabaseCollection::App\Http\Resources\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Models\Database, instance of App\Http\Resources\DatabaseResource given
```

It is a bit strange as i am using this same method for a handful of  controllers and it all works perfect, except this is the only one that returns this error.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not define `Resource` class anywhere so it assumes it should be found in the current namespace `App\Http\Resources`

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

class DatabaseResource extends Resource
```

However Laravel defines Resource class like this.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class UserResource extends JsonResource
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources
So you should update your code accordingly.